# Не работает PlayerPrefs (скорее всего не получает данные)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Все организовал через `HasKey`, если ячейки нету то она создаеться и заполняеться. У меня много ключей и всё работало но когда я сделал локализацию игры (добавил еще один ключ "Language") на пк все работало отлично но когда сделал билд приложения на андроид то данные просто не подгружались (количество монет, выбранный персонаж и т.д), возможно и не сохранялись.

Локализация у меня реализована так

```
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Language"))
{
    language = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Language");
}
else
{
    language = "En";
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Language", language);
}

if (language == "En")
{
    text.text = enText;
}
else
{
    text.text = ruText;
}
```

Ну и скрипт который меняет значение "Language" по нажатию на кнопку. Хотелось бы узнать почему вообще может не работать `PlayerPrefs`?

p.s. когда проверял на пк удалял все данные в реестре.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Это данные для сохранения, а не хранения. В билде ничего не хранится, у каждый создаёт свои данные.

Comment: Вот, поправил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Не ответ.

Но есть мелкий шанс что поможет. Рефакторинг и приведение "в человеческий вид" кода иногда решает вопрос буквально магическим образом.

Необходимо разделить ответственность в коде.

Предлагаю сделать скрипт который задает дефолтные значения на все префы, которые не имеют своего стандартного значения.

Это должен быть скрипт на самой первой сцене на методе `Awake()`

```
public void Awake() 
{
    SetDefaultKeyIfNeeded("Language","En");
}

public void SetDefaultKeyIfNeeded(String key, String value) {
     if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(key)) 
     {
          PlayerPrefs.SetString(key, value);
     }
}
```

А все использования префов должны быть:

- или не раньше `Start()`-а на первой сцене(вероятнее всего это главное меню у тебя).
- или в абсолютно любом месте на иных сценах игры

Это позволит во всех местах пользоваться только  `PlayerPrefs.Get` семейством методов.

т.е. в нужном месте писать просто

```
language = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Language");
```

Фактически так мы отделили установку стандартных значений настроек от использования самих настроек в иных местах программы.

---

Теперь про саму проблему - после того как сделаешь так как я написал выше - если это не решит проблему(что маловероятно, но теоретически возможно) - необходимо  дебажится. Ищи информацию о том как дебажить при запуске игры с телефона.

Просто так здесь на ресурсе вряд ли тебе кто-то угадает в чем именно проблема. Эта проблема решается именно через дебаг.